# Можно ли обучаться программированию с абсолютного нуля?

Tags: c#

Совсем недавно, меня замотивировало программирование. Я посмотрел на некоторые игры, программы, узнал, что они написаны на C#, Unity, c++ и я подумал "Как же это наверное здорово, когда ты сам пишешь код, а потом получается целое приложение, которое в случае удачи, можно выставить в Google Play."

Для начала: знаний по кодам, дизайнам и вообще в целом в этой теме никаких не имею. Вчера я начал
с SoloLearn. Пробовал с C#. Но на втором уроке переменных, сильно усомнился в "легкости". Перешел на Python, там тоже вышли проблемы. Далее я пошел на codeacademy, учить по англ версии. В итоге уже на втором уроке вылезла ошибка сайта, где надо было убрать Run. А как я мог об этом догадаться, если я только начал изучать этот язык С#? Снова пересколчил на Sololearn, а там уже темы сложные. Мне не понятно, у чему меня приведет учеба на codeacademy и SoloLearn. К чему меня приведут уроки "How to learn c# 4/10/15/2/1 hours" и т.п. В итоге я в полной растерянности. Что мне делать дальше?

Comment: В итоге, в чем вопрос? Обучение чему-то новому - всегда без начальных знаний. Чтобы они появились, нужно учиться.

Comment: Если только начинаете, лучше учиться сразу в среде разработки (например, visual studio, если говорить про C#), а не с проверяющими системами типа codecademy. И соответственно учиться по учебнику (бумажному или в электронном варианте).

Comment: codecademy - вообще довольно бесполезный сайт: нужно тупо повторить то что тебе только что показали, в итоге через минуту полученная информация выветривается.

Comment: могу подсказать  неплохую  книжку: "А.Столяров - программирование. Введение в профессию". Начни   с первого   тома,   а  там  глядишь  и     второй   прочтёшь и  затем  третий. Второй   варик -       прочитай   и  попрактикуй  то  что   есть  в первом  томе,     а  затем  попробуй другую  книжку - "М.Доусон - Изучаем с++  через  программирование игр"

Comment: Только   ни в коем случае   не  начинай  изучение программирования    с   языка  c#  и  тем   более     с    каких  либо  игровых  движков - только  чистый  язык  программирования - и  лучший  язык  для  изучения  это  паскаль

Comment: А sololearn стоит использовать? а такие гайды, как обучение за 1 час, за 24 часа эффективны?

Comment: @Slavik - глупости говорите. Человек хочет научиться водить машину, вы ему советуете учиться езде на лошади. / Я вот начинал изучать программирование с машинных кодов (даже не с ассемблера) - было легко и понятно. Так что... каждому своё.

Comment: Если интересен игрострой, то в первую очередь нужно разобраться, чем именно хочется заниматься. Ведь в создании игр кроме программистов принимают участие 3D-моделеры, художники, дизайнеры, композиторы, сценаристы, тестеры... Может вам ближе что-то из этого?

Comment: А ещё я бы советовал сразу учить git, системы учета задач, алгоритмы, слепую машинопись десятью пальцами и английский язык. Ну и устройство автомата Калашникова.

Comment: Вот на мой взгляд толковые [обучающие видео по C#](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ). В паре с умением пользоваться поисковыми, должно помочь обрести базовые навыки. А вообще, начните с алгоритмов (на случай если на информатике в школе вас этому не учили) и ООП. ООП не зависит от языка и везде пригодится, поэтому изучить принципы все равно придется.

Comment: Стоп. Вы можете мне сказать, стоит ли обучаться по Sololearn и видео урокам? На каком этапе можно использовать virtual studio community?

Comment: @Exqualater 1 - обучайтесь как вам удобно. 2 - сразу.

Answer (score 3):

1. а) С Sololearn начинать стоит, хотя бы для ознакомления с предметом.

   б) Далее начинайте смотреть видео уроки и повторять все что там делают (например #SimpleCode).

   в) Затем открывайте учебники или онлайн курсы (напр.: Стивен Прата. ravesli.com).

   Делайте все поэтапно, вначале у вас должна быть железная дисциплина, иначе ничему не научитесь;
2. Visual Studio Community 2019 можете сразу же использовать, для изучения, там много интеллектуальных подсказок для начинающего программиста;
3. Повторяйте по несколько раз пройденный материал, если даже вам кажется что вы все запомнили.

   1-е повторение сразу после изучения

   2-е повторение через 15-20 минут

   3-е повторение через 6-8 часов

   4-е повторение через 24 часа.

Приведены лишь начальные шаги для новичков. Дальше, если пройдёте начальное обучение правильно, многое, для вас, станет понятнее и логичнее.

В Sololearn все максимально сжато и подаётся в лёгкой форме. К тому же это не весь язык, а всего-лишь синтаксис языка.

Сразу всё детально изучать не получится или будет мучительно и долго. Для начала, я бы посоветовал, получить общее представление о предмете в целом, потом начать изучать язык.

Запишите примерный план для себя, чтобы не потеряться в море информации, расставьте маяки, чтобы найти берег, так сказать.

upd. Для лёгкого старта лучше начать с Паскаль или Питона.

Comment: то есть в SoloLearn язык дан в общем обзоре? А как его изучать сразу по мелочам?